# How can I overlay a ProgressSpinner in PrimeNG?

Tags: css, angular, progress-bar, overlay, primeng

I have a progressBar spinner like this :

```
<p-progressSpinner></p-progressSpinner>
```

I want to make it center and overlay. How can I do that ?

Thanks .

Comment: What do you mean by *overlay* ?

Comment: i mean i want to it to be like the primeng dialog .(modal=true)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This works for me: [Original Url](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?p=172192&sid=d763d075d6b92fd3b66e6f988492282a#p172192)

*html*

```
<div class="progress-spinner" *ngIf="true">
    <p-progressSpinner></p-progressSpinner>
</div>
```

*css*

```
.progress-spinner {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    overflow: show;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

/* Transparent Overlay */
.progress-spinner:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.53);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by overlay, but if you want to have a progress spinner inside dialog then

```
<p-dialog [(visible)]="display" [showHeader]="false" [resizable]="false" [modal]="true" [focusOnShow]="false" >
    <i class="pi pi-times" style="float:right" (click)="onCancel()"></i>
    <div style="width: 900px;height: 500px;padding-top: 20%;">
        <p-progressSpinner></p-progressSpinner>
    </div>
</p-dialog>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using PrimeVue (similar to PrimeNG, I think) and this is what I do to get a full-screen overlay with a progress spinner.

In my HTML, I have this...

```
<BlockUI :blocked="isLoading" :fullScreen="true"></BlockUI>
<ProgressSpinner v-show="isLoading" class="overlay"/>
```

Then in my css file I have this style...

```
.overlay {
    position:fixed !important;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    z-index: 100; /* this seems to work for me but may need to be higher*/
}
```

In my TypeScript, I have a reactive variable...

```
const isLoading = ref(false)
```

Then in various functions, I set the state of that variable as needed...

```
isLoading.value = true /* to show overlay + spinner */
isLoading.value = false /* to hide overlay + spinner */
```

Comment: also using primevue, helpful answer!